# How do I apply site-wide styles for H1/H2/.. tags?

Tags: typescript, material-ui

I used to do this:

```
import {createMuiTheme} from '@material-ui/core/styles';

export const theme = createMuiTheme({
  typography: {
    h1: {
      fontSize: '2.85em',
      margin: '0 0 16px', // <-- dies 
    },
    // ..
});
```

But the compiler dies saying margin isn't assignable to TypographyStyleOptions.

> ```
>   TS2326: Types of property 'h1' are incompatible.
> ```
>
> Type '{ fontSize: string; margin: string; }' is not assignable to type 'TypographyStyleOptions'.
>       Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'margin' does not exist in type 'TypographyStyleOptions'.

It used to work before I updated some packages.

Applying styles per component doesn't work for me here because I need those styles in a markdown renderer, which doesn't output React components

Comment: just create a regular style sheet with `h1,h2 {font-size: 2.85em, margin: 0 0 16px}` no need for MUI

Comment: Yeah, might do that. I'm just trying to avoid splitting up my CSS more than necessary. I've also found that just ignoring those lines with `@ts-ignore` works just fine. The styles are applied as I'd expect them to be